# Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError image is not recognized by the 'identify' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

i´m getting this error when editing a model specifically when i delete an image associated to it and I select another:

```
Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Admin/packsController#update

Chrysanthemumprueba4.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

C:/Users/.../vendor/plugins/thoughtbot-paperclip-fc792c8/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:24:in `from_file'
```

But when i create a new pack and I select images for it, it works ok.

I have two tables: packs and pack_images,and pack_images has the photos for the pack associated, here are the relations:

```
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_images, :dependent => :destroy
end

class PackImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pack
  attr_accessor :height, :width

  has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/:attachment/:class/:id/:style_:basename.:extension", :styles => {:principal => "240x240>", :original => "400x400>", ...}

end
```

This is the controller's action that throws me the error:

```
def update
    @pack = Pack.find(params[:id])
    @pack.pack_products

    unless params[:pack][:pack_images_attributes].nil?
      params[:pack][:pack_images_attributes].count.times do |i|
        unless params[:pack][:pack_images_attributes][:"#{i.to_s}"][:photo].blank?
          file = params[:pack][:pack_images_attributes][:"#{i.to_s}"][:photo]
          dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(file)
          @pack.pack_images[i].width = dimensions.width              
          @pack.pack_images[i].height = dimensions.height
        end
      end
    end

  respond_to do |format|
  @pack.update_attributes(params[:pack])
  format.html { redirect_to(admin_pack_path(@pack.id), :notice => 'Pack updated') }

end
```

I noticed that, when updating I get less parameters (only the photo's name) than when creating (photo's name,file type,width,height,etc).

I hope you can help me

Thank you very much

Comment: Please, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771707/1472432

Answer (score 2):

it used to work fine for pdf and images, tried out for an hour or so, followed everything I googled later the problem was found in my model  `has_attached_file :attachment`,

```
:styles => {:original=> "125x125#"}
```

had to comment this line, and it worked for other attachments like docx or odt etc..

so in your case `:styles => {:principal => "240x240>", :original => "400x400>"}`
check out and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the path of the identify command like this:

```
$ which identify
```

For me the above command prints this: `/usr/local/bin/identify`

Add this in some initializer file:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: i'm sorry, I forgot to say that I'm working at windows, how can I obtain that path?

Answer (score 1):

One reason this error occurs is when you try to determine the dimensions of an image that does not exist:

> Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(nil)

This command will hang and cause this error.

Comment: In Ruby/Rails, the error you get is `Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: nil is not recognized by the 'identify' command.` Now I just have to figure out why the file isn't being created...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the "identify" command from ImageMagick on this image. It seems something with your ImageMagick install.

Comment: I did it and it worked OK, it gave me data about the image like width and height, name, etc.

Comment: As Arun said, you will need to set the right path to this command (using **Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:command_path] = 'c:\Program Files\ImageMagick\bin\'**). This path will be the place where the identify.exe command is located. Try checking your $PATH var inside your terminal with: **echo %path%**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Windows 8 64bit, Rails 4, ImageMagick-6.8.7-1-Q16-x64-static.exe. Do this : 
In the root of your rails app (from Git Bash)

```
$ which identify
/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/./identify
```

Then

```
$ cd "/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16"
```

Don't forget the quotes. Copy all executables to you /bin directory. I actually copied all these files to be certain.

```
$ cp * /bin
```

And voila paperclip works!